# How to implement an off-center camera in Godot?

Tags: godot

I'm trying to figure out how one can "offset" a camera within its viewport (the root viewport in this case) to create an off-center camera. To illustrate, using a standard [`Camera` (3D)](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_camera.html) results in a vanishing point of the parallel lines in the center of the screen:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to move the vanishing point a bit to the right, to the center of non-UI area.

I was expecting that [`Camera.h_offset`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_camera.html#class-camera-property-h-offset) has this effect. However, it looks like it is only another way of applying a translation to the camera (i.e., equivalent to translating the camera itself to the left/right):

[image]

Am I missing a trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with a perspective projection. *Well, aside from using a `ViewportContainer` which you move to the side.* You would use a frustum projection instead, and then use `frustum_offset` to skew it. *You probably want to se the size very small.*

Comment: Isn't the approach with a `ViewportContainer` impossible if one wants the 3d view to extend to the left part of the screen as well? I.e., it works only if the GUI on the left doesn't need to be transparent, right?

Comment: @bluenote10 You would have to make it bigger than the actual screen, enough to cover the gap left by simply moving it.